# What (if any) offense is this: Booking the wrong task at the wrong date

Tags: germany, workplace, billing

In German law there exists the concept of "[Scheinrechnung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheinrechnung)" (lit. "pretence invoice"), which, put simply, is an invoice for something that did not actually happen as claimed.

... It would seem though, that this concept does not cover either of these two actions:

- billing for one task, when in truth a different task was done
- billing on dates where no work happened, when the work has actually happened at different dates

And now I wonder:

- Might this even be legal?
- If not, under what law / offense does it fall?
- Is there a difference whether an employee or a contractor does it?

For the purpose of this question, assume that

- the customer had to pay the same amount of money either way (e.g. due to a subscription model, hourly rate, etc.)
- the wrong statements have been made *deliberately*

(If further details are necessary, please ask for them in the comments.)

Being mostly a customer (just like everyone else), I'd rather like this to be very much *not* legal, given that indirect harm may stem from the incorrect information, in an arbitrarily remote future:

- You might have had your car fixed, but the mechanic fixed a different part than reported - when your car breaks next, you will presume it's not the "just fixed" part and might rack up additional mechanic bills (or private time) "on the wrong trail".
- You might be a business trying to analyse your infrastructure needs from work time of contractors - but they actually work on different days, at different hours than reported. If said infrastructure is then lacking (e.g. building closed for renovation), you will pay them for idle time (and might not even notice - given their invoices are wrong).
- You might be a business looking to cut down on expenses - but the expenses you have are not the expenses you know of. So you will cut down on the wrong positions and might disrupt the very processes that earn you money in the first place.
- You might be allergic to a medication administered in hospital, but allegedly you received a different one. (And even if it's a mild allergy requiring no intervention - congratulations, you are now "allergic" to a substance you were never in contact with or tolerated just fine in the past!)

... More cases can easily be constructed, where there is no obvious economic damage (you did receive "your money's worth"), yet "down the line" arbitrarily bad repercussions may arise.

Comment: Note: Not knowing better, I'd presume/hope that _if_ there is regulation against these practices, it would be one and the same one. Should I be mistaken and the two acts ("at different times" vs. "different deeds") are actually handled very differently, I'll gladly split the question in two.

Comment: I don't know enough about German laws to offer an answer,  but some of the examples suggest fraud, false accounting and/or tax evasion..?

Comment: You should clarify between an accidental or deliberate attemt to create a incorrect bill. **Scheinrechnung** assums the latter with the goal of tax fraud. Your samples, however, seem more accidental (or sloppy) and not with the intent to comit tax fraud.

Comment: An employee acts on behalf (**im Auftrag**) of their employer. That is why they should sign any document (bill, receipt etc.) with 'i.A. name'.

Comment: @MarkJohnson : Thank you. I added the clarification that the act would be deliberate (or, in reality I guess, at least _appear_ deliberate).

Comment: @MarkJohnson : Ah, sorry, I think I cannot quite parse your latter comment... ?

Comment: It is still not clear in what form that the person who issued the 'Scheinrechnung' benefits from it. I see no fraud attempt to evade taxes in your samples. For a deliberate incorrect items in a bill, probably other paragraph are relevent.  ; 'Is there a difference whether an employee or ': An employee acts on behalf (im Auftrag) of their employer. So it is a matter of the employer and not the employee.

Comment: @MarkJohnson : One benefit that I have seen cited is skipping paperwork: There might be an established-if-poor business process describing necessary steps for changes to agreed-upon plans (like those of an architect, where _a specific_ material will be denoted, even if there is no need for _that specific_ material). If the change is masked, the steps can be left out. It _might well be_ that no one will suffer from it either, but it cannot be guaranteed. ... Damage might occur though, if the agreed-upon decision had reasons the... err... "skipper" was not privy to.

Comment: Just to expand on my earlier comment, and specifically re the OP's first two bullet points: incorrect billing dates may change when tax is due and payable (eg if it was in a different reporting period it could reduce one's tax bill).  Similarly, different tasks may have different tax liabilities (eg zero, reduced or standard VAT rates) so a bill with an incorrect task could change the liability and *may be* fraud.